# Python split the data with various combinations of single and double quotes

Tags: python, python-2.7

We are trying to split the data based on a delimiter (which is passed from a Configuration File). We are facing issues with various scenarios of data having Single and Double Quotes.

Sample input data are:

```
1|"100001111"|John Payne|100000060
2|'100002222'|John Payne|100000040
3|"100001111|John Payne|100000060
4|100002222"|John Payne|100000040
5|'100001111|John Payne|100000060
6|100002222'|John Payne|100000040
7,100001111,"John,Payne",100000060
8|'100002"222'|John Payne|100000040
9|"100002'222"|John Payne|100000040
10|"100002'222|John Payne|100000040
11|'100002"222|John Payne|100000040
12|100002'222"|John Payne|100000040
13|100002"222'|John Payne|100000040
14,100001111,'John,Payne',100000060
```

We have tried below regex options but not all scenarios are working.

```
re.split('''[,|](?=(?:[^'"]|'[^']*'|"[^"]*")*$)''' , data)
re.split(r'[ ,|;"]+' , data)
```

input

```
8|'100002"222'|John Payne|100000040
```

Output

```
['8' , "'100002"222'" , 'John Payne' , '100000040']
```

Comment: it's unclear what result you want. Note that `csv` module can handle quoting

Comment: We are trying to split the data based on a delimiter which is passed from another file. Data has various combination of single and double quotes in them and it's not splitting correctly.

Comment: I second using the `csv` module. Regexps are a pain to use for parsing, but if you zabsolutely must use them, you might want to preprocess the file before passing it through, maybe by removing or substituting the extra quotes.

Comment: `data.split('|')`?

Answer (score 1):

Creatively using the `csv` module to have different delimiters per each line parsed might do the trick. It's not perfect, though; lines with solitary start-quotes without a matching end-quotes seem tricky.

```
import csv
import io

input_data = """
1|"100001111"|John Payne|100000060
2|'100002222'|John Payne|100000040
3|"100001111|John Payne|100000060
4|100002222"|John Payne|100000040
5|'100001111|John Payne|100000060
6|100002222'|John Payne|100000040
7,100001111,"John,Payne",100000060
8|'100002"222'|John Payne|100000040
9|"100002'222"|John Payne|100000040
10|"100002'222|John Payne|100000040
11|'100002"222|John Payne|100000040
12|100002'222"|John Payne|100000040
13|100002"222'|John Payne|100000040
14,100001111,'John,Payne',100000060
""".strip()

parsed_data = []

for line in input_data.splitlines():
    sep = ('|' if '|' in line else ',')
    reader = csv.reader(io.StringIO(line), delimiter=sep)
    parsed_line = next(reader)
    parsed_data.append(parsed_line)
    print(parsed_line)
```

outputs

```
['1', '100001111', 'John Payne', '100000060']
['2', "'100002222'", 'John Payne', '100000040']
['3', '100001111|John Payne|100000060']
['4', '100002222"', 'John Payne', '100000040']
['5', "'100001111", 'John Payne', '100000060']
['6', "100002222'", 'John Payne', '100000040']
['7', '100001111', 'John,Payne', '100000060']
['8', '\'100002"222\'', 'John Payne', '100000040']
['9', "100002'222", 'John Payne', '100000040']
['10', "100002'222|John Payne|100000040"]
['11', '\'100002"222', 'John Payne', '100000040']
['12', '100002\'222"', 'John Payne', '100000040']
['13', '100002"222\'', 'John Payne', '100000040']
['14', '100001111', "'John", "Payne'", '100000060']
```

Comment: Thanks all of your help.

I am tried below options and it's providing satisfying results.

reader = csv.reader(b , delimiter = dlim , quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
for row in reader:
    c = row[1]

or 

re.split('''[,|](?=(?:[^'"]|'[^']*'|"[^"]*")*$)''' , data